# R extract string matching pattern and before space

Tags: r, string, match, extract, gsub

I am really new to R and having a hard time understanding what the syntax means when trying to extract or gsub the part of a string that I want
My data looks as follows

```
d <- "Para | YTX-456 | XYZ-123456 | NTX-897"
```

I would like to extract "XYZ-123456", so the three specific letters, the "-" and any number that follows up to but *without* the space. Everything I tried so far just extracts the numbers with the space. How can I find a match for "XYZ-" in the string and extract it along with all the numbers that follow?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Andre for your help! Unfortunately this doesn't work as my data is a bit more complex than I described. I will update the post now but basically my strings look as follows "Para | YTX-456 | XYZ-123456 | NTX-897". And I need to extract only the "XYZ-123456". Your response extracts "Para | YTX-456 | XYZ-123456 |"

Comment: `str_extract(d, 'XYZ-[:digit:]*')` - this will pull out "XYZ-" followed by any number of digits. There's a great cheat sheet for the `stringr` package [here](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf), which I almost always have open when I'm using R.

Comment: @C.Murtaugh that's a great resource thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_extract()` here, with `[0-9]+` identifying all numbers after the desired "XYZ-" pattern:

```
stringr::str_extract(d,"XYZ-[0-9]+")

# [1] "XYZ-123456"
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the one I gave, because using `+` after the bracketed regexp, instead of `*` like I did, means that it will only return the extracted string **if** there is at least one number after it. `*` will return it if there are zero or more numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `gsub`, here's a solution with `sub`(which is to be preferred here, as `sub`is used when a single match per string is expected - as in yur case):

```
sub(".*(XYZ\\S+).*", "\\1", d)
[1] "XYZ-123456"
```

Here, we define the substring in question as a capture group by wrapping it into `(` and `)`. The substring itself is matched partly literally (`XYZ`), partly by `\\S+`, a negative character class that matches anything that is **not** a whitespace character.